# pdf2image outputs blank images on certain pdfs

Tags: pdf2image

I have code that converts PDFs to PNG files successfully on almost all PDFs, but I've been trying to convert [this one](https://ia902607.us.archive.org/34/items/reliefsocietymag01reli/reliefsocietymag01reli.pdf), and it only saves blank images of each page.

Note that I am using Windows 10 to do this. I can successfully get pdf2image to output the correct images on Mac OS.

Here is my code:

```
import pdf2image
pdf_path = 'reliefsocietymag01reli.pdf'
info = pdf2image.pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw=None, poppler_path='C:/Program Files/poppler-0.68.0/bin')
page_count = info['Pages']
for page_number in range(1, page_count+1):
    pages = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi=300, first_page=page_number, last_page=page_number+1, poppler_path='C:/Program Files/poppler-0.68.0/bin')
    pages[0].save(f'test - {page_number}.png', 'PNG')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem. It is a problem with Windows that can't really be debugged within the scope of Python. Using a Mac fixed my problem.